# Security setup in Spring Roo M2

Tags: spring, security, installation, roo

I've created project in Spring Roo 2.0.0 M2.
Used "security setup".
But I don't see file applicationContext-security.xml
Where is it?
I tried to use applicationContext-security.xml from version 1.32 but didn't have success.

Answer (score 1):

Roo 2.0 has changed the application configuration model from a model based on XML to the new Java classes model, so now the security is configured in the *SecurityConfiguration.java* class.

On the other side, in Roo 2.0.0 M2, the `security` command has not all the features that it had in Roo 1.0, I hope these features will be added in the M3 or RC1.

Anyway, the security of the applications generated with Roo 2.0.0 M2 can be configured by hand, just edit the *SecurityConfiguration.java* and add your security settings by following the [Spring Security reference doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/)

Good luck